# How to write the boolean function in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl, boolean-logic

I have a Boolean function minimize and I want to create it using VHDL. I created it with circuits and it works perfect but when I create it using VHDL, it gives a different output. Can someone check my Boolean function and code and help debug?

Here is the Boolean function

```
Q0 = A0 + A1 + (~A2 * ~A3 * ~B0 * (B1 + ~B2 * B3))
```

Here is my code for for the boolean function:

```
Q0 <= (A0) or (A1) or (not A2 and not A3 and not B0 and B1) or (not A2 and not A3 and not B0 and not B2 and B3);
```

Comment: Other than the manual application of the distributive law, the two look identical to me. Can you please give us a complete, compilable code example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Looks okay to me. Since you're asking for help debugging, could you give us an idea what's happening that you're not expecting?

Answer (score 2):

In the rewrite to VHDL it looks like you assume that the `*` has higher
priority than `+` in the boolean expression, so the last part of the boolean
expression is as:

```
B1 + ~B2 * B3  = B1 + (~B2 * B3)
```

However, in VHDL the `and` and `or` operators have the same precedence and are
left associative. The `not` operator has higher priority so OK to write before
argument without "()".

So if `+` represents `or`, `*` represents `and`, and `~` represents `not`, then
the last part of the above expression in VHDL is:

```
B1 or not B2 and B3 = (B1 or not B2) and B3
```

The original expression written with VHDL operator precedence is thereby:

```
... ~B0 * ((B1 + ~B2) * B3)
```

So the `*` after `~B0` can not distribute over the `+` in `B1 + ~B2 * B3` when applying VHDL operator precedence of `*` and `+`.

Comment: I assume this is why HellMan manually applied the distributive law. In the given VHDL code, `and` and `or` are not mixed without parentheses, so there is no ambiguity. If he meant `(B1 + ~B2) * B3` in the boolean expression, then of course using the distributive law is incorrect.

Comment: And then there were parenthesis.